# ntpdate on debian

Tags: debian, ntpd

I recently installed ntp on Debian and when issue command:
`ntpdate ip_of_domain_controller` it states: adjust time server.
But the time is 3 hours earlier. Other equipment like HP switches are getting normal time.
Is this a bug from unix side?

Comment: TZ set correctly? Did ntpdate actually reset the time, or was the offset too large? Show the actual output of the ntpdate command.

Comment: What's your timezone? Please show output of `date` and `date -u`. What's the real current time?

Answer (score 1):

It was getting time in UTC, after setting correct timezone everything seems fine

Comment: Pleased to see you're sorted now. Don't forget to use the tick mark to show this is your accepted answer